# Vertx.io core vs reactivex verticle usage in jUnit

Tags: java, testing, junit, vert.x

In my project mostly all imports relay on `io.vertx.reactivex.core.Vertx` package import, effectively makes whole project use `reactivex` (not `core`/vanilla) version of Vertx and it's verticles. I started to unit test a bit our application and to do so and to make it play nicely with JUint, according to this [documentation](https://vertx.io/docs/vertx-unit/java/#_junit_integration) following setup is needed to use JUnit and to run test cases in correct thread and verticle context:

```
@RunWith(VertxUnitRunner.class) /* Set the runner */
public class DaoTest {

    @Rule /* Define rule to get vertx instance in test */
    public RunTestOnContext rule = new RunTestOnContext();

   @Test
    public void exampleTest(TestContext context) {
       TestClass t = new TestClass(rule.vertx());
   }
}
```

the definition of `TestClass` is following:

```
import io.vertx.reactivex.core.Vertx; /* Mind here */
public class TestClass {

    public TestClass(Vertx vertx) {
        /* Something */
    }
```

I'm unable to provide correct instance of `Vertx` because only one definition of `RunTestOnContext` exist in package `io.vertx.ext.unit.junit` and produces `io.vertx.core.Vertx` instance, which is incompatible with `io.vertx.reactivex.core.Vertx` that `TestClass` is using. Some other test utilities, like TestContext have their equivalents in `reactivex` packages `io.vertx.reactivex.ext.unit.TestContext`, but this seems not be a case for `RunTestOnContext`.

The question would be how to obtain correctly `io.vertx.reactivex.core.Vertx` instance in test context to still ensure thread and context consistency?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **vertx-unit** project has only depdendency to **vertx-core**. And has no dependency to **vertx-rx-java**. And that is understandable. Therefore the `RunTestOnContext` is built using the `io.vertx.core.Vertx` as you see.

You can downcast with the `vertx.getDelegate()` from `io.vertx.reactivex.core.Vertx` to `io.vertx.core.Vertx`. Bu that doesnt work in the opposite direction.

Therefore your best option is to copy the code of the `RunTestOnContext` and create your reactivex version of it. (The fastest way is to just change the import to `io.vertx.reactivex.core.Vertx` and use the `vertx.getDelegate()` where it is accessed.)

Comment: By saying "this is understandable" you mean that providing rx-ified version of vertx-unit would not make sense and we have some design flaw? And I think that casting via delegate in this case would be upcasting from formal UML point of view?

Comment: The way vertx went, is that instead of providing an extra util package for vertx-rx-unit, they try to autogenerate code stubs with the @VertxGen annotation from the vertx-util package. That works for example for TestContext etc, as you pointed out. But it wasnt (or couldnt ?) be done for RunOnContext class what you would need right now. Maybe there should be an implementation from it in the vertx-rx-java, but that is not really the package where it belongs. And yes casting from normal vertx to reactivex.Vertx would be an upcasting.

Comment: Hey, I overwritted required classes as you suggested, tests works fine, thanks for suggestions

Comment: YWC, meanwhile one hacky solution came to my mind as well: you can replace your line with `TestClass t = new TestClass(new io.vertx.reactivex.core.Vertx(rule.vertx()));` could work too.

Answer (score 0):

Get RxVertx instance by `rxVertx = Vertx.vertx();` & vertx instance by `rxVertx.getDelegate();`. Here is a full code snippet:

```java
@RunWith(VertxUnitRunner.class)
public class MyVerticleTest {

   protected Vertx vertx;

   @Before
   public void setUp(TestContext context) {
      rxVertx = Vertx.vertx();
      vertx = rxVertx.getDelegate();
      Async async = context.async(1);
      RxHelper.deployVerticle(rxVertx, new MyVerticle())
            .subscribe(res -> async.countDown(), err -> {
               throw new RuntimeException(err);
            });
   }

   @Test
   public void my_test(TestContext context) {
      Async async = context.async();
      rxVertx.eventBus().rxSend("address", dataToSend)
           // .flatMap()
            .subscribe(receivedData -> {
                // assert what you want;
                 async.complete(); 
            }, context::fail);
   }

   @After
   public void tearDown(TestContext context) {
      client.close();
      rxVertx.close(context.asyncAssertSuccess());
   }
}
```

Comment: the major issue is that your solution does not uses `@Rule
    public RunTestOnContext rule = new RunTestOnContext();`, what effectively makes exceptions and context assertions not acessible in test runner thread. See [this](https://vertx.io/docs/vertx-unit/java/#_running_a_test_on_a_vert_x_context) documentation part. For instance running tests from intelliJ IDE all will be passed (since no exceptions were thrown in runner thread)